# Why can't files from sassDir of discovered eyeglass modules be imported?

Tags: sass, gulp-sass, node-sass, eyeglass

I am trying to start using `eyeglass@1.2.1` and am running into problems where, although *eyeglass* modules are discovered, `@import`ing them fails.

Here is the *gulp* task (only wrapped with *gulp* at this point because I don't know how to get pretty *eyeglass* debug output otherwise) which uses *node-sass* to compile a single file.

```
gulp.task('sass', () => {
  const options = eyeglass({
    file: path.join('test', 'test.scss'),
    engines: {
      sass: nodeSass
    }
  });
  return nodeSass.render(options, (err, result) => console.log(err, result));
});
```

This happens:

```
eyeglass:modules discovered modules
eyeglass:modules    :root(test)
eyeglass:modules    ├── eyeglass@1.2.1
eyeglass:modules    ├── eyeglass-sample@0.0.3
eyeglass:modules    └── true@2.2.1
eyeglass:modules     +0ms
eyeglass:functions functions discovered in module eyeglass:
• eyeglass-asset-uri($registered-assets, $relative-path)
• eyeglass-normalize-uri($uri, $type: web)
• eyeglass-uri-preserve($uri)
• eyeglass-uri-restore($uri)
• eyeglass-version($module: eyeglass)
• eyeglass-fs-absolute-path($fs-registered-pathnames, $path-id, $segments...)
• eyeglass-fs-join($segments...)
• eyeglass-fs-exists($absolute-path)
• eyeglass-fs-path-separator()
• eyeglass-fs-list-files($directory, $glob: '*')
• eyeglass-fs-list-directories($directory, $glob: '*')
• eyeglass-fs-parse-filename($filename)
• eyeglass-fs-info($filename)
• eyeglass-fs-read-file($filename) +13ms
eyeglass:functions functions discovered in module eyeglass-sample:
• hello($name) +1ms
eyeglass:functions all discovered functions:
• eyeglass-asset-uri($registered-assets, $relative-path)
• eyeglass-normalize-uri($uri, $type: web)
• eyeglass-uri-preserve($uri)
• eyeglass-uri-restore($uri)
• eyeglass-version($module: eyeglass)
• eyeglass-fs-absolute-path($fs-registered-pathnames, $path-id, $segments...)
• eyeglass-fs-join($segments...)
• eyeglass-fs-exists($absolute-path)
• eyeglass-fs-path-separator()
• eyeglass-fs-list-files($directory, $glob: '*')
• eyeglass-fs-list-directories($directory, $glob: '*')
• eyeglass-fs-parse-filename($filename)
• eyeglass-fs-info($filename)
• eyeglass-fs-read-file($filename)
• hello($name)
[19:25:56] Finished 'sass' after 97 ms
eyeglass:import true can be imported from ~/eyeglass-test/test/test.scss +5ms
{ [Error: Error: Could not import true from any of the following locations:
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/true.scss
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/true.sass
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/true.css
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/_true.scss
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/_true.sass
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/_true.css
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/index.scss
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/index.sass
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/index.css
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/_index.scss
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/_index.sass
  ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/_index.css]
  status: 1,
  file: '~/eyeglass-test/test/test.scss',
  line: 1,
  column: 9,
  message: 'Error: Could not import true from any of the following locations:
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true.scss
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true.sass
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true.css
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/_true.scss
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/_true.sass
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/_true.css
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/index.scss
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/index.sass
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/index.css
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/_index.scss
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/_index.sass
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/_index.css',
      formatted: 'Error: Error: Could not import true from any of the following locations:
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true.scss
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true.sass
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true.css
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/_true.scss
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/_true.sass
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/_true.css
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/index.scss
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/index.sass
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/index.css
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/_index.scss
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/_index.sass
    ~/eyeglass-test/test/true/_index.css
  on line 1 of test/test.scss
  >> @import "true";
     --------^
  ' } null
```

I've tried this with several potential *eyeglass* dependencies, e.g.

- eyeglass-sample
- eyeglass-math
- susy
- true

I get the same type of failure for all of them, where they appear to be available in debug output, but attempting to `@import` them by name or `@import` anything in their `sass` directories fails.

I get these failures even when very *specific* messages that say things ***are*** importable show up:

```
eyeglass:import susy can be imported from ~/eyeglass-test/sass/_test.scss +14ms
...
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
```

If I start from scratch again, I run into this, which I've gotten past (though I don't remember how):

```
> DEBUG=* gulp sass
[12:51:50] Requiring external module babel-register
[12:51:53] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/eyeglass-test/gulpfile.babel.js
[12:51:53] Starting 'sass'...
  eyeglass:modules discovered modules
  eyeglass:modules  :root(eyeglass-test)
  eyeglass:modules  ├── eyeglass@1.2.1
  eyeglass:modules  └── susy@2.2.12
  eyeglass:modules   +0ms
[12:51:53] 'sass' errored after 29 ms
[12:51:53] TypeError: this.main is not a function
    at EyeglassModule.init (~/eyeglass-test/node_modules/eyeglass/lib/modules/EyeglassModule.js:80:33)
    at ~/eyeglass-test/node_modules/eyeglass/lib/modules/EyeglassModules.js:83:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at EyeglassModules.init (~/eyeglass-test/node_modules/eyeglass/lib/modules/EyeglassModules.js:82:13)
    at new Eyeglass (~/eyeglass-test/node_modules/eyeglass/lib/index.js:35:16)
    at Eyeglass (~/eyeglass-test/node_modules/eyeglass/lib/index.js:18:13)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (~/eyeglass-test/gulpfile.babel.js:7:19)
    at module.exports (~/eyeglass-test/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (~/eyeglass-test/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (~/eyeglass-test/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
```

The above is the most simplified case for illustration purposes. I have tried this using alternatives from *eyeglass* docs and issues such as `new Eyeglass` and `eyeglass.Eyeglass` and `eyeglass.sassOptions()`. I have tried it with and without `enableImportOnce: false`.  I've tried manually adding the modules via the *eyeglass* options.  I have tried it with and without `engines`. I have tried it with and without providing a default `importer` as mentioned in *eyeglass* docs and issues. I've tried it using *node-sass*, *gulp-sass*, and *sass-true*'s runner method (through which *true* but nothing else can be imported because *true* adds itself to `includePaths`).

The only thing I have *not* tried--although I am very sure it will work--is manually creating my own `includePaths` configuration to include the sass directories of the *eyeglass* modules, because not having to do that is one of two reasons I'm interested in using *eyeglass*. I'd gotten the impression that ***typically*** it isn't supposed to be necessary to set up `includePaths` to use *eyeglass* modules, but, assuming it's caused by something I'm doing, it's not clear to me what inevitable common circumstance I've created in all of these various attempts that has consistently required my doing so.

Cross posted to https://github.com/sass-eyeglass/eyeglass/issues/164

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this several times, but had to put it down for a bit. When I came back to it and set up individual examples for the various things I tried, I discovered that I had gotten further than I'd thought and my main issues were:

1. True is unique. There're still some parts of how to best work with True and eyeglass that I'm fuzzy on, but the main points are there.
2. Eyeglass doesn't support transitive dependencies **if they are `devDependencies`**; module authors need to make sure to list any eyeglass dependencies in `dependencies`.

Here are all the examples I ultimately created for troubleshooting, in case they are useful to others.

https://github.com/morewry/sass-eyeglass-examples